# File Close Notification

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wish to know when another application finishes editing a file.

I am aware of [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch2s8yd7.aspx) class, however I think these are only able to detect file creation and changes. Which won't allow me to know whether the file still has content which will be written to it in future or not. One solution would be to wait to ensure that all data has been written, but I feel that there should be a better way.

I wish to know when the process writing to the file closes the handle it has, I think writing a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968) may allow for this, can anyone confirm? Or provide another method I which I could use. Also I would prefer not to rely on something like .net but I wouldn't rule it out.

Thanks very much, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can poll this by trying to open the file in exclusive mode.

On windows you can use OpenFile with OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE.

Comment: +1  It's not a great solution, but it's probably the only one that works without a filter driver, which is a huge investment for the problem at hand.

Comment: Unfortunately it's likely that another process will also want to read the file afterwards.

Comment: Have a look at this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files). They can determine which process has a file open.